# Why can expectation and ratio be exchanged in this case?

Tags: probability

From [Simulation and the Monte Carlo Method by Reuven Y. Rubinstein, Dirk P. Kroese](http://books.google.com/books?id=1-ffZVmazvwC&lpg=PP1&vq=If%20the%20conditions%20in%20%28b%29%20hold,%20the%20steady-state%20expected%20value,&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Let $\{X_t\}$ be a regenerative process with regeneration times
>   $T_0,T_l,\dots$ Let $r_i = T_i - T_{i-1} i = 1,2,\dots$ be the cycle
>   lengths. Depending on whether $\{X_t\}$ is a discrete-time or
>   continuous-time process, define, for some real-valued function $H$, $$
>  R_i= \sum_{t=T_{i-1}}^{T_i-1} H(X_t), (4.21) $$ or $$R_i=
>  \int_{T_{i-1}}^{T_i} H(X_t)dt, (4.22)$$ respectively, for $i = 1, 2,
>  \dots$. We assume for simplicity that $T_0 = 0$. We also assume that
>   in the discrete case the cycle lengths are not always a multiple of
>   some integer greater than
>   1.  Let $r = T_i$ and $R = R_i$.
>
> If $E[r] < \infty$, then, under mild conditions, the process $\{X_t\}$
>   has a limiting (or steady-state) distribution, in the sense that there
>   exists a random variable $X$, such that $$\lim_{t\to \infty} P(X_t \leq
>  x) = P(X \leq x) .$$ In the discrete case, no extra condition is
>   required. In the continuous case a sufficient condition is that the
>   sample paths of the process are right-continuous and that the cycle
>   length distribution is non-lattice — that is, the distribution does
>   not concentrate all its probability mass at points $n \delta, n \in
>  \mathbb{N}$, for some $\delta > 0$.
>
> If the above conditions hold, then the steady-state expected value is
>   given by $$ E[H(X)] = \frac{E[R]}{E[r]}. (4.23)$$

If I am correct, $H(X) = R/r$. But how can expectation and ration exchange their order in $ E[H(X)] = \frac{E[R]}{E[r]}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see that H(X)=R/r?

Comment: @did: I messed it up. It may not be true. See my answer please. Thanks!

Comment: A remarkable euphemism, if ever there was one.

Comment: I beg your pardon, if I can?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily true that $H(X) = R/r$.

In the discrete case 
$$
\frac{E[R]}{E[r]} = \frac{E[\sum_{t=0}^{r - 1} H(X_t)]}{E[r]}
=  \frac{E[ E(\sum_{t=0}^{T - 1} H(X_t) | r=T)]}{E[r]}
=  \frac{E[ r E(H(X))]}{E[r]}
= E(H(X)).
$$

In the continuous case, use Fubini's theorem to prove it. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236752/is-e-int-0t-x-t-dt-t-ex-t-when-x-ts-are-identically-distributed).